# renaming file names containing colon with mv in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I know that my issue seems very simple but it took me a day and no luck. I have checked many other posts but none of them solved my problem. I have some files

```
touch wrfchemi_d01_2010061500:00:00
touch wrfchemi_d01_2010061600:00:00
touch wrfchemi_d01_2010061700:00:00
touch wrfchemi_d01_2010061800:00:00
```

I want to rename them to:

wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_15_00:00:00
wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_16_00:00:00
wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_17_00:00:00
wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_18_00:00:00

I wrote a simple script

```
for item in `ls wrfchemi*`
do
year=`echo "$item" | cut -c14-17`
mon=`echo "$item" | cut -c18-19`
day=`echo "$item" | cut -c20-21`
hr=`echo "$item" | cut -c22-23`
dat="wrfchemi_d01_"$year"_"$mon"_"$day"_"$hr":00:00"
echo $dat
mv $item "$dat"
done
```

It throws out this error

mv: cannot move 'wrfchemi_d01_2010061500:00:00' to 'wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_15_00:00:00': No such file or directory

mv: cannot move 'wrfchemi_d01_2010061600:00:00' to 'wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_16_00:00:00': No such file or directory

mv: cannot move 'wrfchemi_d01_2010061700:00:00' to 'wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_17_00:00:00': No such file or directory

mv: cannot move 'wrfchemi_d01_2010061800:00:00' to 'wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_18_00:00:00': No such file or directory

**UPDATE:**

SO weird. It also fails in terminal whereas file does exists. It automatically adds "\" to zeros

```
 "mv wrfchemi_d01_2010061500\:00\:00 wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_15_00:00:00"
```

but it still causes the error

> No such file or directory

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to do the `mv` by hand in the same directory?

Comment: Not sure if it's your issue, but the first line is safer and more efficient to do as `for item in wrfchemi*`.  You might also like to add `ls - l $dat` and `touch $item` to your script, to make sure that the file is where you think it is, and that you are able to create files in this directory as you expect.

Comment: Which operating system, and which filesystem? I'd also suggest running `set -x` to enable logging. And as a completely unrelated issue -- don't ever use `ls` in scripts; it's only for interactive use. Run `for item in wrfchemi*; do ...` alone; it's both faster and more correct.

Comment: @NateEldredge so weird. It also fails in terminal while file does exists. It automatically adds \ "mv wrfchemi_d01_2010061500\:00\:00 wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_15_00:00:00"

Comment: BTW, the `echo "$item" | cut ...` is really inefficient. It's much faster to run `year=${item:13:4}`. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe describing that syntax (parameter expansion) specifically, or [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), *How do I do string manipulations in bash?*

Comment: @SeyedOmidNabavi, so, is it `ls` adding those backslashes? If so, just stop using it, as I describe above; `for item in wrfchemi*` will leave the names exactly as they literally are (though `set -x` logging may still quote them to allow unambiguous printing).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used for item in  wrfchemi*; but it still fails. The problem is that I cannot even rename through terminal. What do you mean with "set -x". Where should I put it?

Comment: `set -x` tells the shell to log each command it performs. Put it anywhere in the script after the shebang and before the `for` loop.

Comment: BTW, `mv "$item" "$dat"`, and `echo "$dat"` -- you should be quoting **all** expansions.

Comment: Similarly, `dat="wrfchemi_d01_${year}_${mon}_${day}_${hr}:00:00"` -- you want to keep the parameter expansions quoted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it does not work

Comment: *shrug*. With correct quoting, your code has fewer bugs than it had with incorrect quoting. It may not have fixed the specific bug you came here for, but it's still fixing bugs nonetheless.

Comment: Anyhow, again, collect a `set -x` log and [edit] it into the question.

Comment: ...and by the way -- what's your operating system, and your filesystem? `:` in a filename has a special meaning in some places, including on Windows.

Comment: regarding set -x, I put it before for loop and it just prints out each variable on the terminal. I see no log file. I use NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian

Comment: Yes, printing each command on the terminal is exactly what it's supposed to do. I didn't say it would log *to a file*, just that it would generate a trace log.

Comment: `"mv wrfchemi_d01_2010061500\:00\:00 wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_15_00:00:00"` is *supposed* to generate an error, because the quoting is all wrong. There's no surprise there. Generate a `set -x` log, don't do whatever you did that built that.

Comment: When you put the whole command in a single set of quotes, it's looking for a single command named `mv wrfchemi_d01_2010061500:00:00 wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_15_00:00:00`, not a command named `mv` to pass the arguments `wrfchemi_d01_2010061500:00:00` and `wrfchemi_d01_2010_06_15_00:00:00`. Each *argument* should be quoted separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `rename`:

```
rename 's/_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/_$1_$2_$3_/' wrfchemi_d01_??????????:*
```

By using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
for file in wrfchemi_d01_??????????:*;do
    mv "$file" "${file:0:17}_${file:17:2}_${file:19:2}_${file:21}"
done
```

Comment: I tried your code in centos (in a bash script) and it worked. Many thanks.